# JQuery .click() handler can't accept setTimeout() around the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to program a delay in the .click(function() {...}) handler before the function is executed.  This doesn't work:

```
$('.okButton').click(setTimeout(function() { ...}, 3000))
```

It gives this error (in Chrome):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 2 has no method 'apply'
```

The JQuery docs don't give any clue as to why this doesn't work.

How can I put a delay before executing the function handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to have a .click() handler function that just calls setTimeout() with a handle to the real handler function:

```
  $('.okButton').click(function() {
        setTimeout(okButtonClickHandler, 3000)
  });
```

When I tried this before it called the handler function immediately because I include parenthesis on the argument to setTimeout().

Don't do this:

```
  $('.okButton').click(function() {
        setTimeout(okButtonClickHandler(), 3000)
  });
```

It will execute the handler function immediately.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't work because `setTimeout()` doesn't return a function; it returns a timer handle (a number).

This should work:

```
$('.okButton').click(function() { setTimeout(function() { ...}, 3000); });
```

The argument expressions in JavaScript function calls are always fully evaluated *before* the function is called. Your code called `setTimeout()`, and the return value from that was passed into the jQuery routine.

Comment: This and the other examples like it don't work because JS executes the entire handler immediately and then executes the function argument in setTimeout() after the time specified.  setTimeout() does not delay processing the rest of the handler until it times out.

Comment: @DeanSchulze I don't understand what you mean. Are you trying to delay the establishment of a "click" handler, or do you want the "click" handler to set a timer so that something happens 3 seconds after the "click"?  If the latter, then this is definitely how you do it.  I'll make a jsfiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: I want to delay the execution of the click handler itself.  Putting the setTimeout() inside the handler delays the other function declared in setTimeout().  It does not delay processing the rest of the click handler.

Comment: @DeanSchulze so put all the code that you need delayed inside the timeout callback. You cannot make JavaScript execution pause.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put the timeout inside the callback?

```
$('.okButton').click(function() {

  setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Hello");
  },3000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$(".okbutton").click(function(event) {
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Foo");
    }, 3000)
});
```

You can try out the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/HvNZM/). After clicking the word click it takes three seconds for the alert to appear.